# Moq not resolving ICollection reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq

I am using Moq.4.2.1507.0118 and I'm having a problem that I have not seen before. The situation is that I have two classes in my model (A and B) with a one to many relationship. For example:

```
[Table("A")]
public partial class A
{

    public A()
    {
        this.theB = new HashSet<B>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int AId{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<B> theB{ get; set; }

}

[Table("B")]
public partial class B
{
    [Key]
    public int BId{ get; set; }
    public int AId{ get; set; }
    public virtual A theA { get; set; }
}
```

Of course I also have the DbSet's defined in the DbContext.

Then, in my test code, I have:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        var theAs = new List<A>
        {
            new A{ AId=1, Name="test" }
        };
        var theBs= new List<B>
        {
            new B{ BId=1, AId=1, theA=theAs[0] }
        };

        var ASet= new Mock<DbSet<A>>().SetupData(theAs);
        var BSet= new Mock<DbSet<B>>().SetupData(theBs);

        var context = new Mock<MyContext>();
        context.Setup(s => s.A).Returns(ASet.Object);
        context.Setup(s => s.B).Returns(BSet.Object);

        var m = new ClassThatImTesting(context);
        m.someMethod("test");
    }
```

Normally I would see that this is enough to let A and B know about each other in the mock context. However, in the method that I'm testing, if I run something like this:

```
var result = context.A.Where(x => x.theB.Count() > 0).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get null. Since I've done this in so many other tests without a problem, I'm having a hard time seeing what I've done to trip this up. Any ideas would be helpful! I've simplified this example from my actual code, so please forgive syntax errors.

Comment: As an aside, it might be worth using a (non-generic) repository pattern instead of testing a dbcontext like this. You should trust that the db context works.

Comment: I don't see where you are instantiating 'theB' to the object "theAs"

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra - You mean: theAs[0].theB = theBs;? I've tried that and it didn't help. Also, I've never had to do that before.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace and the code where you are getting the NullReferenceException?

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra - There's no error, it just returns null.

Comment: Can you update then the code and post where did you added this line `theAs[0].theB = theBs;` and it didn't work?

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra - Doh, you were right, I must not have assigned that correctly before. That was indeed the problem. Please post as an answer and I'll mark it as such. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra - One other note, it always seemed like Moq did the work to fill in both sides of the relationship once you filled in one side. EF itself does this, as you probably know, when you SaveChanges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate the collection to the A object before injecting the context to the class.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        var theAs = new List<A>
        {
            new A{ AId=1, Name="test" }
        };
        var theBs= new List<B>
        {
            new B{ BId=1, AId=1, theA=theAs[0] }
        };
        //here
        theAs[0].theB = theBs

        var ASet= new Mock<DbSet<A>>().SetupData(theAs);
        var BSet= new Mock<DbSet<B>>().SetupData(theBs);

        var context = new Mock<MyContext>();
        context.Setup(s => s.A).Returns(ASet.Object);
        context.Setup(s => s.B).Returns(BSet.Object);

        var m = new ClassThatImTesting(context);
        m.someMethod("test");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for making the blind see :)